# Question I stuck with, is it open or close?

Tags: functions

I came across this question in my test, let $f:R->R$ be defined by $f(t)=t^2$ and let $U$ be any non-empty open subset of $R$, Then

```
 1. f(U) is open 
 2. f^-1(U) is open 
 3. f(U) is closed 
 4. f^-1(U) is closed
```

The option I thought was correct is (1.) but (2.) is correct I don't know why?
I think option 1 is correct because U is an open subset of R hence the function will also map to a set which is open. 
So please tell me how option 2 is correct and which concept I don't know about or not getting to answer this question. 
I would like a hint.

Answer (score 1):

Hint to help you consider the potential issue:

If $U =(-1,4)$ then what might $f(U)$ and $f^{-1}(U)$ represent?

Comment: $f^{-1}(U)$ is not defined for -ve values of U(-1,4) as inverse of f is $\sqrt{t}$ no? thanks for help

Comment: @Abomm: If $U=(-1,4)$ then $f(U)=[0,16)$ while $f^{-1}(U) = (-2,2)$ - it is the set of $x$ such that $f(x) \in U$ - so assertions 1, 3 and 4 would be false in this case, while assertion 2 would be correct (and in fact assertion 2 is correct  for all non-empty open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$)